# How can I tell WebMatrix where to put the project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

The problem with using Visual Studio to create a web site project (File | New Website | ASP.NET Web Site (Razor 2)) is that it gives you no option to start off with an empty site. The problem with WebMatrix, OTOH, is that it doesn't let you specify where (on the hard drive) to put your site, and doesn't make it obvious where it places it, either.

*Is* there a way to force WebMatrix to store the site in a particular place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File » Options » Site » Default site location